# Construction of G-invariant section of vector bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, vector-bundles

Suppose $E \rightarrow M$ is a vector bundle, and $G$ a Lie group acting by vector bundle automorphisms on $E$, such that the action on the base is proper. Is it true that given any smooth section $\sigma$ of $E$ one can construct a $G$-invariant section of $E$?

I found something in a paper where a special section was needed to give you some nice construction. This section was proved to exist, and then there was the comment that if you have a $G$-action, one can choose a $G$-invariant open cover of $M$, and make the section $\sigma$ $G$-invariant over each open set of the cover by averaging, using that the stabilizer groups are compact. Finally, you glue everything together with a $G$-invariant partition of unity. This would give a $G$-invariant version of the result.

I am not familiar with this "averaging" process. Could you explain what is really meant?

Comment: Is $G$ compact?

Comment: @AlexM. No it's not, I only want $G$ to act properly on $M$.

Comment: The zero section is $G$-invariant; conversely, if $G$ is a Lie group acting by bundle automorphisms over the identity map (e.g., scalar multiplication by non-zero real numbers), then in many cases the only $G$-invariant section is identically zero. Is this really what you mean to ask...? (If not, could you perhaps clarify the intended role of $\sigma$ in constructing a $G$-invariant section? Particularly, how does the desired goal differ from, "There exists a $G$-invariant section"?)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I modified my question, I hope now it's not confusing.

Comment: The customary idiom in this situation is to let $d\mu$ be a unit-volume left-invariant measure on $G$, and (modulo details of left- versus right actions, etc.) to replace $\sigma$ with its average under integration over $G$: $\int_{G} (g^{-1})^{*}\sigma\, d\mu$. The simplest example comes from the multiplicative actions of $\{\pm1\}$ on the trivial real line bundle over the non-zero reals, with $(-1)(x, v) = (-x, \pm v)$. A section is just a function $f$, and the respective averaged (i.e. invariant) sections are the even and odd parts of $f$: $\frac{1}{2}(f(x) \pm f(-x))$.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang: This is why I asked whether $G$ is compact, but apparently it's not, so $\mu$ might not exist.

Comment: @AlexM.: Yes, I'm aware of that you asked, and that $G$ is not compact. OP's edit made it seem as if they didn't know the story even for compact $G$. Of course, I may have misconstrued... :)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Ok I see, so $G$ in my case is the stabilizer group which is compact and hence admits the volume. I will try to average over this and then extend it to a whole neighborhood. I guess that's what I need. Thanks for your time guys! :D

Comment: @T.P.: Does $E$ also carry a Hermitian or Euclidian structure (i.e. some sort of fiber-wise scalar product)? Is $M$ compact and Riemannian? These ingredients would help a lot.